# Basic SASS - Nesting and HTML Syntax

Tags: css, sass

I just started using SASS however I can't seem to find a clear answer/example for this.

Say I have:

```
<img class="socialIcons" src="/images/facebook.png"/>
<img class="socialIcons" src="/images/google.png"/>
```

I now want to have some additional styles for Facebook and Google - is there some clever SASS syntax I can use for example so I get:

```
<img class="socialIcons-facebook" src="/images/facebook.png"/>
<img class="socialIcons-google" src="/images/google.png"/>
```

And in my SASS use:

```
.socialIcons {
  max-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;

  &.facebook {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

So that it adopts the general `socialIcons` style as well as `Facebook`.

Can't seem to figure the syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

```
<img class="socialIcons facebook" src="/images/facebook.png"/>
<img class="socialIcons google" src="/images/google.png"/>
```

The '&' syntax will match an element that has both the outer class and the class with the & selector.  You can overwrite the 'socialIcons' class with the more specific nested selector.  No need to change the Sass.

Comment: Ahh! Yes thats it - a simple as removing that hypen! Many Thanks.